# Button Not Responding On Click To Remove Element

Tags: jquery

I'm normally a backend developer and don't do much on the front end, but I have a major project I am responsible for end to end. As such, I'm trying to use Twitter Bootstrap and jQuery but am finding myself stuck when trying to remove a list item I previously created using jQuery. I feel I am missing something obvious but can't figure out what it is.

Here is the code, the Remove From Order section is the one that doesn't do anything when the button is clicked -- nothing at all seems to happen:

EDIT: Couldn't get Jsfiddle to play nice, so I've added the HTML here with the code. Everything is either inline (as this is a test file) or called via CDN.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>

            </title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <meta name="description" content="">
            <meta name="author" content="">
            <!-- Le styles -->
            <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
            <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
            <![endif]-->
            <!-- Fav and touch icons -->
            <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
            <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
            <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
            <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="ico/favicon.png">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/prettyCheckable/prettyCheckable.css">
            <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" />
            <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.selectboxit/3.5.0/jquery.selectBoxIt.css" />

            <script src="js/prettyCheckable/prettyCheckable.js"></script>
            <script>
                    $().ready(function(){

                      $('input.fancyCheckbox').prettyCheckable();

                      //Calls the selectBoxIt method on your HTML select box.
                      $("select").selectBoxIt({
                            theme: "bootstrap",
                            showFirstOption: false
                        });

                       $(".poptip").popover({ trigger: "hover" });
                       $(".inputpopover").popover({ trigger: "focus" });

                       $(".tip").tooltip();


                        // Add To Order Button Click Code
                        $('#idsp-test').keyup(function () {
                            // console.log(this.value);
                            if(parseInt(this.value) > 0) {
                                $('#btn-idsp-add').show();
                            }
                            else {
                                $('#btn-idsp-add').hide();
                            }
                        });

                        $("#btn-idsp-add").on('click', function(){
                            $("#addons_list").append('<li id="idsp-addon-list-item"><i class="icon-ok"></i> ' + $('#idsp-test').val() + ' IDSP <button class="btn btn-mini btn-danger" id="btn-idsp-remove" type="button">Remove From Order</button></li>');
                            // Hide Button After Adding to Sidebar
                            $('#btn-idsp-add').fadeOut('slow');
                        });

                        // REMOVE FROM ORDER BUTTONS
                        $('#btn-idsp-remove').on('click',function(){
                            $('#idsp-test').val('0');
                            $('#idsp-addon-list-item').remove();
                        });

                    });
            </script>
            <style type="text/css">
                .selectboxit-container .selectboxit-options {
                    /* Set's the drop down options width to the same width as the drop down button */
                    width: 210px;
                    /* Set's the max-height property to only show a subset of the drop down items.
                                           If you do not set a max-height property, SelectBoxIt will dynamically
                                           position the dropdown (when opened) to make sure the drop down items are not
                                           displayed outside of the current window viewport.
                                        */
                    max-height: 240px;
                }

                #btn-idsp-add, #btn-county-crim-add {
                    display: none;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <h1>Package and Addon Selection</h1>
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="span4">
                            <form action="index.cfm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                <legend>Package Selection</legend>
                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <select id="package_select" name="package_select" class="package_selection">
                                            <option>Basic Packages</option>
                                            <option data-selectedtext = "Standard SmartPak Selected" data-content="Standard SmartPak" value="standard">Standard SmartPak</option>
                                            <option data-selectedtext = "Advanced SmartPak Selected" data-content="Advanced SmartPak" value="advanced">Advanced SmartPak</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                <div class="alert alert-success" style="margin-top: 6px; box-shadow: 0 0 2px">
                                <h5>This Package Includes:</h5>
                                    <ul class="unstyled">
                                        <li><i class="icon-ok"></i> One</li>
                                        <li><i class="icon-ok"></i> Two</li>
                                        <li><i class="icon-ok"></i> Three</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <hr>
                                <div id="addons_list_box" class="alert alert-info" style="box-shadow: 0 0 2px">
                                <h5>Additional Addon Items:</h5>
                                    <ul class="unstyled" id="addons_list"></ul>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="span8">
                            <fieldset>
                            <!-- Form Name -->
                            <legend>Order Add Ons</legend>
                            <!-- Multiple Checkboxes -->
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <div class="controls controls-row">
                                    <div class="input-wrapper form-inline">
                                        <label for="idsp-test">IDSP
                                        <input type="text" class="mini inline inputpopover" title="Additional IDSPs" data-content="Enter a number from 1 to 10 to add to your order.  Set to zero and click the button to remove or change." data-placement="top" id="idsp-test" name="idsp-test" placeholder="Add a Quantity from 1 to 10." value="" autocomplete="off" />
                                        <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" id="btn-idsp-add"><i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i> Add/Update Order</button>
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="controls controls-row">
                                    <div class="input-wrapper form-inline">
                                        <label for="county-crim-test">County Criminal Search
                                        <input type="text" class="mini inline inputpopover" title="Additional County Criminal Searches" data-content="Enter a number from 1 to 10 to add to your order.  Set to zero and click the button to remove or change." data-placement="top" id="county-crim-test" name="county-crim-test" placeholder="Add a Quantity from 1 to 10." value="" autocomplete="off" />
                                        <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" id="btn-county-crim-add"><i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i> Add/Update Order</button>
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- Button -->
                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <label class="control-label"></label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <input name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" title="Submit the Form" value="Place My Order" data-toggle="tooltip" data-content="Submit The Form" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </fieldset>
                    </form>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /container -->
    <!-- Le javascript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.selectboxit/3.5.0/jquery.selectBoxIt.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/prettyCheckable/prettyCheckable.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Can someone tell me what I've done wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Where is `HTML` code?

Comment: Can you create a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Yeah, that's not working, my crystal ball told me yesterday that the issue was the selector, and it should be `$('#ill_add_markup').remove()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though it kind of defeats the point of ".on", try changing the click event to this:

```
// REMOVE FROM ORDER BUTTONS
$(document).on('click', '#btn-idsp-remove', function(){
    $('#idsp-test').val('0');
    $('ul').find('#idsp-addon-list-item').remove();  //assumes you are using "ul" for your list and not "ol"
});
```

And a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pLR56/) to go with it.

Comment: I refactored the entire page and code, but the problem resurfaced — this solution worked. What is it about this implementation that works? Also, do I have to add this code for each of the buttons I want it to work with?

Comment: In your previous code, when javascript reads your click event on the remove button --> $('#btn-idsp-remove').on('click',function(){... it binds to an element that doesn't exist. So when you dynamically create the remove button later (using the append method, triggered by a click event on the existing "add" button), this remove button has no events binded to it.

Comment: So you have 2 choices. You can bind it again, by calling the --> $('#btn-idsp-remove').on('click',function(){... after you appended it OR you can bind to a parent (the parent existed already, was not dynamically added after) and listen for the event. So using the ".on" I choose the "document" as the parent, which is the most broad (and inefficient) parent to listen on. But you have to specify the child, so that only events that "bubble" up to the document from this child will trigger.

Comment: Here's a link that kind of helps explain (however it's discussing the now depreciated "live" method, which "on" is now used for): http://www.alfajango.com/blog/the-difference-between-jquerys-bind-live-and-delegate/

Comment: One way you can also think about it is this: did you create the element dynamically? If so, then choose your jquery selector wisely, choose an element that already exists and use that as a reference point to help jquery find the dynamic element you are interested in. $('some parent up the tree here').on('click', 'some dynamically created child down the tree here', function(){... The closer the parent is to the child, the more efficient.